# Aren't «...» quotation marks more of a German thing than they are Swiss?

Tags: swiss-german, swiss-standard-german, typography, quotes

Someone wrote that typographic conventions in Switzerland, like the usage of «...» instead of „...“ as quotation mark, sets them apart from German press.

Aren't «...» quotation marks more of a German thing though than it is Swiss? Some historical context on useage over the years would be helpful. Other comparative examples of media-press conventions are welcome.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3075/why-are-the-german-guillemets-inverted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

«...» is typically considered Swiss German or French style by origin. Irrespective the origin and where whatever style is common, any single medium or publisher may choose to use whatever they like as a matter to express their own style:

From [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen):

- Andrea fragte mich: „Hast du Grass’ ‚Blechtrommel‘ gelesen?“ (in Deutschland und Österreich, deutsch)
- Andrea fragte mich: »Hast du Grass’ ›Blechtrommel‹ gelesen?« (Chevrons in Deutschland und Österreich)
- Andrea fragte mich: «Hast du Grass’ ‹Blechtrommel› gelesen?» (Guillemets in der deutschen Schweiz, ohne Abstände)
- Andrea m’a demandé : « As-tu lu “Le Tambour” de Grass ? » (Guillemets in Frankreich, mit kleinem Abstand)
- Andrea m’a demandé : «As-tu lu ‹Le Tambour› de Grass?» (Guillemets in der französischen Schweiz, ohne Abstände)
- Andrea fragte mich: "Hast du Grass' 'Blechtrommel' gelesen?" (Schreibmaschinensatz)

There is [evidence in this typographic guide](https://typefacts.com/artikel/anfuehrungszeichen) that the Guillemets are also rather used reversed in German text (compared to French / Swiss German usage):

> Die »französischen« Anführungszeichen werden nach ihrem wahrscheinlichen Erfinder Guillaume Le Bé auch Guillemets (»kleine Willis«) genannt. Im Deutschen werden sie im Gegensatz zum Französischen und Schweizerischen »nach innen zeigend« verwendet, obwohl grundsätzlich auch nichts gegen die umgekehrte Verwendung spricht.